# Generic scanner driver for Mac

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, scanner

I have an old CanoScan D646u scanner (~2003). I can't find any drivers for it on the Mac OS X (10.6.6). Is there something I can do? I'm thinking of a generic TWAIN driver, if that would work. I'm not sure where to start, though.

Answer (score 1):

Give **[Vuescan](http://www.hamrick.com/)** a try.  They support a large selection of older scanners.  It's not free, but they do have a trial version that might get things working!